# Move map if feature is not fitting in map view after changing it's coordinates in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

There is a feature as Icon on the map. The feature is moved by changing coordinates. In some moment it is disapered on the map view. How to move map if feature is not fitting in map view?

```
const iconFeature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point([0, 0]),
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500,
});

const iconStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    src: 'data/icon.png',
  }),
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: [iconFeature],
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
});

iconFeature.setCoordinates([35, 55]); // This draws features outside of viewbox.
```

How to auto move map on this point if feature not fittting in map view box?

Comment: Thank you, I updated

Comment: You could check if point is outside of viewport every time you add a feature with something like `map.getView().calculateExtent().containsCoordinate(coord)` and then change the view using `view.fit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way of setting feature coordinates and then moving it into view if new coordinates are outside current view would be:

- Calculate view extent with `map.getView().calculateExtent()`
- Calculate `diffX` and `diffY` which represent how far new coordinates are outside the view extent.
- Use `map.getView().animate` method with `center` option to change map center for `[diffX, diffY]` ammount, adding some buffer value so that feature ends well within view.

Code could then look something like this (assuming view projection is standard Web Mercator):

```
function setFeatureCoord(feature, coord) {
  var buffPerc = 0.05;
  var view = map.getView();
  var coord = ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord);
  var extent = view.calculateExtent();

  var width = Math.abs(extent[0] - extent[2]);
  var height =  Math.abs(extent[1] - extent[3]);
  var buffX = width * buffPerc;
  var buffY = height * buffPerc;
  
  var diffX = 0;
  if (coord[0] < extent[0])
    diffX = coord[0] - extent[0] - buffX;
  else if (coord[0] > extent[2]) {
    diffX = coord[0] - extent[2] + buffX;
  }

  var diffY = 0;        
  if (coord[1] < extent[1])
    diffY = coord[1] - extent[1] - buffY;
  else if (coord[1] > extent[3]) {
    diffY = coord[1] - extent[3] + buffY;
  }
  
  feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(coord);
  if ((diffX == 0) && (diffY == 0)) return;

  var center = view.getCenter();
  view.animate({
    center: [center[0] + diffX, center[1] + diffY]
  });
}
```

In your case call would then look like:

```
setFeatureCoord(iconFeature, [35, 55]);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, could you check my new question, it is eays I think